Install C,C++,g++ compililer as non root user
Is there a way to install a C,C++,g++ compililer on my home directory as non root user. I need a compiler since I need to install gcc but I got the following error during the config.
configure: line 1821: g++: command not found

The OS is: redhat enterprise_linux 7.9
Regards!

Nix, docker, proot, chroot, podman
